# Reading the value of a child without knowing the value key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I want to get a specific data value (it is circled in green) that was previously pushed. But when I run this code it also displays the key.

[This is the Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2odRF.jpg)

The class in which I push the data:

```java
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getEmail();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

reference.child(user.getUid()).child("Distance").push().setValue(LastValueRounded);
reference.child(user.getUid()).child("Speed").push().setValue(averagespeed);
reference.child(user.getUid()).child("Time").push().setValue(getTimerText());
```

The class where I'm supposed to read the data:

```java
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getEmail();
DatabaseReference reference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference("Users");

reference.orderByChild("email")
         .equalTo(uid)
         .addValueEventListener(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snapshot.child("Distance").getValue() != null) {
                    String distance1 = snapshot.child("Distance").getValue().toString();
                    String speed1 = snapshot.child("Speed").getValue().toString();
                    String time1 = snapshot.child("Time").getValue().toString();
                 
                    distance.setText(distance1);
                    speed.setText(speed1);
                    time.setText(time1);
                }
            }
        }        

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("ERROR", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

[The displayed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3f1i.png)

Comment: Please do not link to images. The information in the images you've linked can be inlined into your question as text.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the following reference:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
reference.orderByChild("email")
     .equalTo(uid)
     .addValueEventListener(/* ... /*);
```

It means that you are trying to get all children under the "Users" node where the "email" field holds the value of the UID of the authenticated users, but this is not correct since under the "Users" node there are no such children. To be able to get only the values that correspond to those pushed elements, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            for (DataSnapshot distanceSnapshot : snapshot.child("Distance").getChildren()) {
                distance.setText(distanceSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }
            for (DataSnapshot speedSnapshot : snapshot.child("Speed").getChildren()) {
                speed.setText(speedSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }
            for (DataSnapshot timeSnapshot : snapshot.child("Time").getChildren()) {
                time.setText(timeSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your "getValue()" returns a Map object.  You may want to try:

```
String distance1 = (String)(snapshot.child("Distance").getValue().get("MJw...9") );
```